# Why aren't handlers listed as a property in Apple's Class Reference?

Tags: ios, swift, class, oop

For example, looking at UIAlertAction, we see that there's a convenience initializer as follows:

```
convenience init(title title: String?,
           style style: UIAlertActionStyle,
         handler handler: ((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?)
```

However, when looking at [the class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertAction_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIAlertAction/title), the `handler` is not listed as a property. It's only `title`, `style`, and `enabled`. Is this because the handler is encapsulated and non-accessible by other classes, or is the handler not stored as a class variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this because the handler is encapsulated and non-accessible by other classes?

Yes.

You can easily do this with your own types by making the member `private`:

```
class C
{
    private var block: (() -> Void)?

    init(_ block: (() -> Void)?) {
        self.block = block
    }
}
```

The three levels of access control are:

- `private` values are accessible within the **same file only**.
- `internal` values are accessible within the **same module only** (but across multiple files in the same module).
- `public` values are accessible **from other modules** as well.

If you compile with testing enabled, you can also use `@testable import MyModule` to get access to `internal` stuff from a separate Test target.

See the docs for more details about [Access Control](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html).

Comment: Wow! Really cool. Thanks! So none of the private variables are listed in apple's class reference?

Comment: Yup. Only `public` things get exposed to other modules. (Note that `internal` is the default.)